# CentralPlanner API cal via curl. 500 response

Tags: php, curl

I have done little with cURL so far, so bear with me.

This is the api that I am currently dealing with:
[CentralPlannerAPI](https://42he.com/de/developer/cp)

I have a token, I can call it via the bash shell and all is fine, except for the part where PHP comes into play. I constantly get authentication errors. The last one would be a 500.

**This one works:**

```
 curl "https://centralplanner.net/api/contacts" -H 'Authorization: Token token="my-api-token"'
```

**This one does not work:**

```
 $ch = curl_init();

 curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://centralplanner.net/api/contacts/count" );
 curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( "Authorization: Token token='myToken'" ) );

 curl_exec( $ch );
 curl_close( $ch );
```

Why does the PHP part not work?

What am I not getting here. Yes, there is currently not much to it and later one it will only be slightly more than this, at least from the current perspective; no it will not run on a server; yes, I will add some validation on and yes, it will a proper class construct and so and so forth.

PS:
Before someone refers me to other SO sites, I looked at them ... did not help.

Comment: What do you mean "it wont run on a server"? You need, at minimum, PHP installed in order to execute a PHP script.

Comment: Server vs local ... thank you... only local ... not in the wild

Comment: Well a 500 is a server error, is that coming from your server or is that the error you get from the API?

Comment: It's still a server then ;) do you have PHP installed locally? How are you running this? Is CURL enabled / PHP enabled?

Comment: You are using different quotes for myToken in CLI and PHP. You can escape double-quotes in the string by escaping them like `\"`.

Comment: @prodigitalson From the API. My xampp installation runs fine.

Comment: @Adam basic xampp stuff with some stuff added to the core, because it did not have it in the first place.

Comment: @Tobias K ... I hate the escaping ... I hate it so much. Every day on work I hate and now I hate it even more. Thanks ... that did it. I have a proper result: {"total_entries": 1}; Actually, I tried this before posting the question, but in a different kind of way ...

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
$ch = curl_init("https://centralplanner.net/api/contacts/count");
$options = [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => "Authorization: Token token=\"myToken\""
];
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

$content = curl_exec($ch);
```